# How can I limit the input year on @mui/x-date-pickers to a specific range?

Tags: javascript, next.js, material-ui, datepicker

I use @mui/x-date-pickers. Can I limit the input year, for example from 1000 to 2023? Now I can enter years like 0000 or 9999.

[image]

```
My datePicker, I tried to put mask into InputProps, but It doesn't work   

``<DatePicker
      label={label}
      value={value}
      open={isOpen}
      onChange={onChange}
      onOpen={changeIsOpen(true)}
      onClose={changeIsOpen(false)}
      className={styles.box__picker}
      slotProps={{
        popper: { className: styles.box },
        textField: {
          helperText,
          error,
        },
      }}
      minDate={MIN_DATE}
      maxDate={MAX_DATE}
   />``
```

Answer (score -1):

you can limit the input year in `@mui/x-date-pickers` by using the minDate and maxDate props. The `minDate` prop specifies the earliest date that can be selected, and the `maxDate` prop specifies the latest date that can be selected. In your case, you would set the minDate prop to 1000 and the maxDate prop to 2023. and also add `readOnly: true,` so the user cannot type the date only can select the date by popup model.

Note that the `minDate` and `maxDate` props accept Date objects, so you will need to convert your desired dates to Date objects before passing them to these props. You can use the `new Date()` constructor to do this.
Here is an update code:

```
<DatePicker
      label={label}
      value={value}
      open={isOpen}
      onChange={onChange}
      onOpen={changeIsOpen(true)}
      onClose={changeIsOpen(false)}
      className={styles.box__picker}
      slotProps={{
        popper: { className: styles.box },
        textField: {
          helperText,
          error,
          readOnly: true,
        },
      }}
      minDate={new Date(1000, 0, 1)}
      maxDate={new Date(2023, 12, 31)}
   />
```

alternative you use also use the `moment.js` package for this

```
minDate={moment('01-01-1000').toDate()}
maxDate={moment('12-31-2023').toDate()}
```

Comment: thx for your answer, I have minDate and maxDate, but when I type value in input, there I wanna limit from 1000 to 2023

Comment: http://joxi.ru/GrqNMd5TbdM8Qm

Here I have range limit. The problem is when I type value in input

Comment: there might be issue in your object.
in above mentioned code 
use this
`minDate={new Date(1000, 0, 1)}`
`maxDate={new Date(2023, 12, 31)}`
to limit the range from 1000 to 2023

Comment: http://joxi.ru/brRbDEvc8zbMJr

I still can type like this(

Comment: this basically blocks the user type the input but use can select the date by pop-up model
For @mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.1.0":
`<DatePicker      
    slotProps={{
        textField: {
            readOnly: true,
        },
    }}
/>`

code is now update according to it.

Comment: Note that `minDate={new Date(1000, 0, 1)}` and `maxDate={new Date(2023, 12, 31)}` will not work unless you have upgraded @mui/x-date-pickers to version 6 or above. Prior to that version, DatePicker did NOT accept Date objects for the minDate and maxDate props, contrary to the claim. It should be a date adapter function, like the ones mentioned with moment.